# Return zero value if division by zero is encountered in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, divide-by-zero

I'm working on a project where I'm dividing one array with another array and the problem is that the array I'm dividing with contains some elements that have the value zero. This gives me the warning "Division by zero" and also returns the value "INF". I want the division by zero to return the value zero if possible. I'm quite new to programming and would appreciate it if someone could help me out or give some hints on how to solve this. Below is a simplified case of the problem.

```
    $arr1 = array(10, 20, 30);
    $arr2 = array(1, 2, 0);
    $arr3 = array_map(function ($a,$b) {return $a / $b;}, $arr1, $arr2);
    print_r($arr3);
```

So the output is currently:

```
Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 10 [2] => INF )
```

And the output I want is:

```
Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 10 [2] => 0 )
```

Comment: `if ($b === 0) { return 0; }` ?

Comment: I am not sure what the issue is. You try to divide by zero which you can't do. Make your  codedeal with `$b` values that are zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if the parameter is zero:

```php
$arr1 = [10, 20, 30];
$arr2 = [1, 2, 0];
$arr3 = array_map(function ($a, $b) {
    if($b === 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $a / $b;
}, $arr1, $arr2);
print_r($arr3);
```